# Wordpress function to show last three posts -> excerpt not working good

Tags: php, wordpress, post, posts

I have a php function that should print last three posts: title and excerpt.

For the first post printed there is no excerpt.

Here is the code:

```
  $posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array('numberposts' => 3, 'post_status' => 'publish')  );
  foreach ($posts as $post)
  {
    setup_postdata($post);
    echo "<h2 style='font-size:18px'>".$post['post_title']."</h2>";
    if($post['post_excerpt']) 
         echo $post['post_excerpt']." <a href='".get_permalink($post['ID'])."'     style='font-size: 17px;'><b>Continue...</b></a>";
    else echo 'no excerpt';
    echo "<br><br />";
  }
```

I want to shoe the excerpt for the first post printed too (the last posted one).
What is wrong in my code? Why it's not working for the first post printed?

Comment: I created a plugin in wich i register a sidebar widget. In this plugin i'm using the code above, please tell me if you have another idea of how to show the latest posts. This works almost good, for the first post that is retrieved, the excerpt is missing (if I add a new post, the problem will be the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is strange. Why not just use a regular [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) loop?

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    the_excerpt();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

or if you are MARRIED to yours, do `var_dump( $posts )` and see what variable contains the string you're looking for.

Comment: @RaresP. Then please mark this as answered. It helps for future users and visitors that might have the same question as you.